# How can i start gif from certain frame

Tags: java, gif

So I made a flamethrower gif and I want the flames to start at a random frame so it looks a bit better. They now all start at the same frame.

Does someone know how I can start a gif from a random/certain frame?

This is how I draw my gif. I know you can do it easily if you use sprites to draw the gif, but i dont feel like doing all that right now.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.fire.size(); i++)
{
    if(m.fire.get(i).visible)
    {
        drawFireFlame(g, (int) (m.fire.get(i).getxPositie()),
                         (int) (m.fire.get(i).getyPositie()));
    }
}


public void drawFireFlame(Graphics g, int x, int y)
{
    Image fire = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image/fire.gif");
    g.drawImage(fire, x - 20, y - 38, 40, 40, null);
}
```